# Subgroup of "equivariant" maps?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition, group-actions

Given a $G$-set $X$, I've checked that the set:
$$E(G,X,\cdot):=\lbrace f\in\operatorname{Sym}(X)\mid f(g\cdot x)=g\cdot f(x), \text{ for all }g \text{ and all }x\rbrace$$
is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$. Unless it is always $E(G,X,\cdot)=\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ (possibily for some trivial reason I'm missing), does this subgroup have a name?

Comment: It is definitely not true that $E(G,X,\cdot)= \operatorname{Sym}(X)$. Examples are quite easy to construct. Your subgroup is exactly the set of all $G$-automorphisms of $X$.

Comment: You are right, @J.DeRo. Take e.g. $X=G$ and "$\cdot$" the left multiplication by a fixed element of $G$; then, $E(G,G,\cdot)$ trivially intersects with $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, and hence cannot be the whole $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just the automorphism group of the $G$-set $X$. The concept of [automorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/automorphism) groups makes sense in every [category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category), and here you have the [category of $G$-sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+G-sets). In my opinion, giving these groups special names obscures the fact that they are the same concept (in disguise, when you ignore basic category theory).

The reason that some authors prefer to say "equivariant automorphisms", "linear automorphisms", "bijective isometries" etc. instead of just "automorphisms" is to hide the usual implicit application of [forgetful functors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/forgetful+functor) (here: from $G$-spaces to spaces, or $G$-sets to sets).

Comment: Just a side note. For $X=G$ we'd have then variously "the automorphism group of the $G$-set $G$" or (see @J.DeRo's comment above) the group of all "the $G$-automorphisms of $G$". Both wordings tremendously sound like "the automorphism group of $G$" despite the fact that $E(G,G,\text{left multip.})\cap\operatorname{Aut}(G)=\{Id_G\}$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: They sound like something else only when you secretly apply forgetful functors.

Comment: I was pretty sure that cathegory theory settled it all. Perhaps one day I'll dive into it.